# Determine whether or not database field is type TEXT

Tags: php, mysql, database, field

I'm working on an edit view which takes a database table as argument, then loads the fieldnames and display textboxes, textareas etc.

However, I don't really want textboxes for every field. Some fields in my database are of the TEXT type; for them i want to display a textarea. Other fields are TINYINT, for them I want to display a checkbox.

Is it possible to determine the type of a database field and then work from that in my PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Maybe using `SHOW COLUMNS FROM MaTable;` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SHOW COLUMNS FROM table;` provides the information you'll need.

Have a look here for more information http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html

Comment: or `mysql_query("DESCRIBE table");`

Comment: Good alternative, I had overlooked the php tag.

Answer (score 3):

[mysql_field_type](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-field-type.php) function may be useful

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL, this function might help you: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-type.php